# what is join order in sql

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Does join order is determined on mention of table in sequence or on the order of tables in 'on' clause?

Is

```
select *
  from A 
  left 
  join B 
    on A.id=B.id
```

same as

```
select * 
  from A 
  left 
  join B 
    on B.id = A.id
```

?

Comment: Yes, the order is determined by which table is 'operand' of JOIN clause only.

Comment: I chose to mark as duplicate because the accepted answers are probably nicer and more helpful than anything you would receive here.  If you are really stuck on something, drop a note and someone can reopen the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although I prefer the second option. It sounds more like natural language to my ear.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. The logical conditions are commutative. Read here for more insights on [MySQL joins.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)